# B^ is random or not? True and False question and Why?

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing

[image]

The OLS estimator  B^ is a random variable due to the assumption that Xi  is a random
variable. is this true or false and why?

Comment: This isn't clear as it stands.  Is this about a regression coefficient estimate? Something else? What is the relationship between beta and x?

Comment: yes regression coefficient estimate

Comment: The most common regression specification takes the x's as fixed values. This contradicts the quotation you gave.

Comment: There are situations possible where the randomness in the OLS estimator is completely due to randomness in $X$. For instance, think about a model where $Y = a + b X + c X^2 + \epsilon$ where the noise is equal to zero, ie. $\epsilon = 0$, and we fit this model with a simple linear regression. Then for fixed $X$ you will always get the same result, but when $X$ is random then the fit will also be random.

Comment: So it is a bit difficult to answer the question. We know that often the randomness of $Y$ results in randomness of the estimator/fit, but sometimes it is also randomness in $X$ that plays a role, and (as in the example above) it can also be that randomness in $X$ is essential (I agree that the example is manufactured and unnatural/weird). But what does the phrase mean "$\hat{\beta}_1 $is a random variable due to the assumption that $X_1$ is a random variable"? This sounds like an exam question with some specific context. But asked on a forum like here we can get wild variations.

Comment: It sounds like this is asking an exam or homework question, looking for a free answer.

Comment: @Shadow Yes, clearly it is, and would be closed for that reason alone according to the [tag:self-study] wiki.  Because it already has an answer here, though, closing it as a duplicate is more constructive.  (Indeed, more research on CV will turn up many more variants of the same answer.)

Answer (score 2):

Even if $X_i$ were fixed, $\hat\beta$ would be a random variable as the OLS estimator is a function of $y_i$, which is a r.v. even if $X_i$ is assumed to be fixed in repeated samples.